# Magento login redirection

Tags: magento-1.9

i used `System" > "Configuration" > "Customer Configuration" section "Login Options" not does that when set to "no"`

it work's fine in top link. But if i used in view page but it redirect to my account

```
<a class="c-login" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>"> Login/ Create Account</a>
```

What is problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your question got down voted, anyhow, take a look at the AccountController.php file `_loginPostRedirect()`

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php#L190

for details on how the redirect works, normally it is set based on the refer URL, so if you are logging in through the account area, the login will direct back to the same account page afterwards.